# How to loop over a file, yet based on the order of another file, in bash?

Tags: bash, scripting

Let's say I have this file, called `Dependencies`:

```
Accounts
Blog
Configuration
Contacts
Entities
Faqs
Forms
Galleries
Geo
Globalization
Logs
Media
Navigation
Notifications
Orders
Payment
Places
Pricing
Products
Sales
Seo
Services
Shipment
Social
Subscriptions
Taxonomy
Ticketing
```

I can loop over it using many methods and have each line as a variable to do something with it.

Yet, I have another file called `Order`, which is like this:

```
Entities
Globalization
Configuration
Accounts
Contacts
Taxonomy
Geo
Media
Places
Products
Services
Orders
Shipment
Payment
Sales
Social
```

This means I need to load lines of `Dependencies` based on the order specified in the `Order` file. And if a line does not exist in the `Order` file, it goes to the end of the list and the order is not essential for it there.

In C#, I can easily use `dependencies.OrderBy(i => orders.IndexOf(i))` to list my dependencies, based on the orders specified.

But I'm stuck on how can I do this in bash.

Comment: There are things in Dependencies not in Order, but are there things in Order not in Dependencies? If not, you could just output Order, and then output everything in Dependencies not in Order afterwards. `cat Order && comm -23 <(sort Dependencies) <(sort Order)`.

Comment: @frabjous, yep, there are many `Dependencies` files, each belonging to a different project, and each depending on a different set of modules. Thus it's possible to have things in `Order` not present in `Dependencies`.

Answer (score 3):

I assume every line in `Dependencies` is unique. The same for `Order`. Such assumption seems sane for your use case.

Invoke this:

```
grep -xFf Dependencies Order; grep -vxFf Order Dependencies
```

The first `grep` gives you lines that are in `Dependencies` and in `Order`, in the order from `Order`.

The second `grep` gives you lines that are in `Dependencies` but not in `Order`. These are lines from `Dependencies` that were not printed by the first `grep`.

In total every line from `Dependencies` should appear.

The assumption of uniqueness is relevant because a line duplicated in `Dependencies` or a line duplicated in `Order` may appear many times in the output, but possibly not exactly as many times as its count in `Dependencies`. Its count in the output will depend on which `grep` prints it.

Comment: worked like a charm. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```bash
awk '
    FNR == NR {
        words[$0]
        next
    }
    ($0 in words) {
        print
        delete words[$0]
    }
    END {
        for (word in words)
            print word
    }' Dependencies Order
```

This first read the lines from `Dependencies` into the associative array `words` as keys.  It then reads the lines from `Order`, and if a string is a key in the `words` array, it prints it and deletes that key from the array.  In the end, all remaining keys in `words` are printed.

Note that the order in which the final list of lines is printed may not be fixed as it depends on the order of retrieval of the keys in the `words` array.

Testing:

```bash
$ awk 'FNR == NR { words[$0]; next } ($0 in words) { print; delete words[$0] } END { for (word in words) print word }' Dependencies Order
Entities
Globalization
Configuration
Accounts
Contacts
Taxonomy
Geo
Media
Places
Products
Services
Orders
Shipment
Payment
Sales
Social
Galleries
Subscriptions
Seo
Faqs
Notifications
Ticketing
Forms
Navigation
Blog
Pricing
Logs
```

---

The above code would remove duplicates. If you want to retain any duplicates in `Dependencies`, then keep track of the number of times each line from that file has been seen, and then output the line that many times.

```bash
awk '
    FNR == NR {
        words[$0]++
        next
    }
    ($0 in words) {
        while (words[$0]-- > 0) print
        delete words[$0]
    }
    END {
        for (word in words)
            while (words[word]-- > 0) print word
    }' Dependencies Order
```

Answer (score 1):

If using `zsh` instead of `bash`, you could take the same indexof() approach by doing:

```
order=( ${(f)"$(<Order)"} )
dependencies=(
  /(Ne['
        reply=( ${(f)"$(<Dependencies)"} )
     ']noe['
        REPLY=$order[(ie)$REPLY]
     '])
)
```

And then:

```
for dep in $dependencies; do
  ...
done
```

To loop over them.

We use the `noe[code]` glob qualifiers to `n`umerically `o`rder the glob expansion based on the value of `$REPLY` as modified by the `code`. The glob expansion (here applied to `/`) is seeded by filling up `$reply` with the lines of the `Dependencies` file (like we filled up the `$order` array with the lines of the `Order` file earlier) using the `e` qualifier.

`$order[(ie)$REPLY]` expands to the `i`ndex of the first element of `$order` that matches with `$REPLY`, `e`xact match with `e`. And 1 + the last index if there's not match.

Another approach could be to use the array intersection `${a:*b}` and subtraction (`${a:|b}`) operators:

```
order=( ${(f)"$(<Order)"} )
dependencies=( ${(f)"$(<Dependencies)"} )

dependencies=(
  ${order:*dependencies} # elements or $order that are also in $dependencies
  # followed by:
  ${dependencies:|order} # elements of $dependencies that are not in $order
)
```